# Accessing attributes of a derived class in a std::list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

What I want to do is that I have a list `std::list<Displayable> display_queue`

Displayable being defined in `Displayable.h` as:

```
class Displayable { 

    public:

        int x, y;

        Displayable() : x(0), y(0) {}
        Displayable(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

};
```

and `DifferentDisplayable` as:

```
class DifferentDisplayable : public Displayable { 

    public:

        std::string id;

        DifferentDisplayable() : Displayable(), id("") {}
        DifferentDisplayable(int x, int y) : Displayable(x, y), id("") {}
        DifferentDisplayable(int x, int y, std::string id) : Displayable(x, y), id(id) {} 

};
```

The items added to the list is:

```
Displayable disp_one;
DifferentDisplayable disp_two(10, 10, "the id");

display_queue.push_back(disp);
display_queue.push_back(disp_two);
```

Since `DifferentDisplayable` is derived from `Displayable` it is able to be stored in the list but what I can't figure out is how can I or can I even access `std::string id` in `DifferentDisplayable` when iterating through the list (display_queue) like so:

```
for (std::list<Displayable>::iterator i = display_queue.begin(); i != display_queue.end(); i++) {

    // insert code here

}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: [You better read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). You're about to embark upon an object-slicing problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [push\_back with derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540998/push-back-with-derived-class)

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241680/list-of-polymorphic-objects

Comment: @WhozCraig By the time I see the issue and post the answer, you already made the comment which I didn't see. Why not post it as an answer when it is the answer ?

Comment: @Mahesh It falls somewhat into a grey area, and I understand that. The "problem" the OP is *going* to have is the same one addressed in the linked q&a. But the *question* is actually different (but obviously soon-to-be-related). The OP didn't ask "Why does this not work" because they didn't get that far yet. The question essentially was "How do I do this?" and the answer is "Not like *that*." (and +1 on your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'id' isn't needed for all derived classes, then instead of trying to access it directly from your loop, add a base class method that uses it. For example:

```
class Displayable
{
public:
  virtual void Display();
  ...
};
```

(Even better would be to make 'class Displayable' an abstract base class, with Display() as a pure virtual function. See the links below.)

Then the implementations can vary independently:

```
void Displayable::Display()
{
  // Do something here with 'x' and 'y'
}

void DifferentDisplayable::Display()
{
  // Do something here with 'x', 'y', and 'id'
}
```

Then allocate your objects on the heap to avoid the slicing problem:

```
Displayable* disp_one = new Displayable();
DifferentDisplayable* disp_two = new DifferentDisplayable(10, 10, "the id");

display_queue.push_back(disp);
display_queue.push_back(disp_two);
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
for (std::list<Displayable>::iterator i = display_queue.begin(); i != display_queue.end(); ++i) {
  (*i)->Display();
}
```

Remember to 'delete' the pointers when you're done with them.

This strategy is discussed in the [Open-Closed Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf) and in Item 34 "Differentiate between inheritance of interface and inheritance of implementation" in [Effective C++ 3rd Edition by Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876).

Answer (score 2):

```
std::list<Displayable> display_queue;
```

The list is capable of holding only `Displayable` objects but not it's any derived sub-objects. When you try to do `display_queue.push_back(disp_two);`, object is sliced and only base class sub-object is stored in the list.